# Unity - Access to svPosition in fragment shader

Tags: unity, opengl, shaders, directx, cg

I am trying to access to the `svPosition` in my fragment program in Unity but I keep having this error.

> invalid input semantic 'POSITION': Legal indices are in `[1,15]` invalid `ps_3_0` input semantic 'POSITION'

Here are some information about my whole shader.

```
struct : float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
vertex : o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
fragment : col.rgb = i.pos.xyz;
```

Any idea how to access this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, you're using shader model 3.0.  According to the documentation of [System Value Semantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx#System_Value), they are not available in DX9.  You will have to use shader model 4.0 or you will simply not be able to use this semantic.

Add this to your shader:

```
#pragma target 4.0
```

Comment: Thanks ! Any workaround to transfer `svPosition` into fragment shader in DX9 ?

Comment: @MaT typically I just include two entries in the vertex-to-fragment struct: one tagged SV_POSITION for use in rasterizing the primitive, and one tagged as a TEXCOORD to use as a shader input. Then I assign the projected position to both variables. It costs one extra interpolator slot, but in my experience that hasn't been a problem. Don't forget that you'll probably want to do a perspective divide in your fragment shader - you may get unexpected results trying to use the undivided x, y, z components directly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread in the Unity Answers, maybe it will be of some assistance?

edit(after being reprimanded ;D ):
apparently, you cant just pass the SV_POSITION to the pixel(fragment) shader. this link shows a workaround by storing the SV_POSITION in a separate texcoord, and giving the fragment shader as input a struct with both texcoords (TEXCOORD0 and TEXCOORD1). Then inside the pixel shader you can use TEXCOORD1 to you liking.

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/utilizing-position-in-your-fragment-output-causes-semantic-error-in-d3d9-mode.345200/

Comment: Hi and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange. Link-only answers are discouraged here, because they become cryptic or useless if the document they're referencing ever moves or goes offline. When you want to share a link, you should always include at least a summary of what information at the link you think will be helpful in answering the question. This both makes it easier to pick out the useful information when linking large documents, and makes your answer more robust against link-rot.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks. I'v probably read the short version of the rules somewhere, but I guess I didn't bother to remember them.